# object.scale not rendering in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, three.js

So, I'm trying to make individual cubes in a 5x5 Rubik's cube like object scale depending on an audio files frequency. I don't know why it isn't working. Could anyone help out?

```
function render() {
    analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(signal);

    var max = 300;
    var i, cube;
    for(i < 0; i < allCubes; i++){
        cube = allCubes[i];
        cube.scale.z = 1 + (-1 * signal[i]/max);
    }

    camera.position.x = Math.sin(cameraAngle) * 400;
    camera.position.y = Math.sin(cameraAngle * 1.35) * 300;
    camera.position.z = Math.cos(cameraAngle) * 200;
    cameraAngle += 0.01;
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);             
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
}
```

This should change the individual cubes to increase in size on the z-axis.

Comment: What is signal[i]? Log the scale you're setting to make sure it's not NaN

Comment: Also the result of this part `(-1 * signal[i]/max)` can be 0, as `signal[i]` is 0.

Comment: signal is a Float32Array with values from -300 to 0 for decibels. I did console.log and they returned correctly for the most part, but for the first 2 logs, it displayed an array filled with "-infinity'. Could that be causing the issue?

Comment: What is `object.scale` supposed to refer to?